# How to pull data from MariaDB using REST api?

Tags: node.js, rest, mariadb

I am really new to both MariaDB and REST api.
I want to query the database and display it on webpage.

Example:

```
Database = MyDB
 -----------------------------
| ID | First Name | Last Name |
-------------------------------
|  1 | Bob        | Smith     |
|  2 | Marry      | Gold      |
|  3 | Sandy      | Jones     |
-------------------------------
```

In a web browser:

http://www.example.com/Database=MyDB?LastName=Smith (I just want to specify the database name and query it and be able to display the output)

The output is:

```
-------------------------------
| ID | First Name | Last Name |
-------------------------------
| 1  | Bob        | Smith     |
-------------------------------
```

I thought of using NodeJS for this but I am still a little confused on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with express and any number of ORM modules.

My Preference is to use bookshelf.js as an ORM to access the database and restify to serve the web service. You would set up routes in restify that use handler functions that call bookshelf methods to CRUD yours models.

I am currently developing the module dreamcatcher which does this